# How can I display the weights and bias from LinearRegression()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to solve a linear regression problem and I'm using the `LinearRegression()` function from `sklearn`. Is it possible to display the weights and bias?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you `fit` the model use `coef_` attribute to retrive weights and `intercept_` to get bias term.

See below example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 

a = np.array([[5,8],[12,24],[19,11],[10,15]])

## weights
w = np.array([0.2, 0.5])

## bias  
b = 0.1  

y = np.matmul(w, a.T) + b

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(a, y)

print(lr.coef_)
# array([0.2, 0.5])

print(lr.intercept_)
# 0.099
```

For more details refer [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)